# javascript add class to an anchor when page loaded

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to add a second class to my element

**Before**

```
<div class="foo1">
    <a class="class1" >Text</a>
</div>
```

**After**

```
<div class="foo1">
    <a class="class1 class2" >Text</a>
</div>
```

here is my javascript code (tried but no success):

```
window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById('class1').className = 'class2';
};
```

***UPDATE***
actually, all of your answers work, but since this (class1) is a click event, by running the codes it temporarily adds the second class (class2) to the class1 but when page is reloaded , it has disappeared. I need to implement it via a click event by clicking class1. How do I do it?

***2nd UPDATE***
actually the site users have the ability to change this class, so I am trying to make this happen: that a user changes a class by clicking on class1 and making it "class1 class2"

Comment: You don't have any element that satisfies this selector: `document.getElementById('class1')`.

Comment: Please describe what you have tried so far.  This is made simple in jQuery, and also doable in plain-ol' javascript.

Comment: @ne1410s I'd say it's pretty simple in plain JS as well. Plus, no need for a heavy (and mostly useless :X ) library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get all the elements with that class:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('class1');
```

Then loop over them:

```
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++)
```

You need to concat the values:

```
element.className += ' class2';
```

So the full code looks like this:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('class1');

for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    var element = elements[i];
    element.className += ' class2';
}
```

---

Example (`.class2` elements have red colour):

```js
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('class1');

for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    var element = elements[i];
    element.className += ' class2';
}
```

```css
.class2 {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<div class="class1">1</div>
<div class="class1">2</div>
```

---

Or, if your browser supports `classList` (as most modern browsers do), then something like this will work as well:

```
element.classList.add('class2');
```

---

AFTER THE QUESTION UPDATE

> but since this is a click event, it temporarily adds the second class but when page is reloaded , it has disappeared. I need to implement it via a click event. How do I do it?

Ideally, you'd use a server-side language to maintain changed classes after a page reloads. Normally, when you reload a page, your whole DOM reloads (including the classes).

There is a client-side solution, but not recommended: use a storage mechanism, like sessionStorage, localStorage, or plain old cookie, to keep track of click events. And then, when you render the page, simply check the storage for those click events you tracked, and adjust classes accordingly using the code above.

Why not recommended? Because this is a way of faking a server-side behaviour using a client-side language. Ideally, if you want to keep things on the client, you'd avoid the page reload completely and have everything happen on a single page (like SPAs do). But I'm afraid I can't tell you much more unless you provide more details about what are you trying to do.

Here's a super-simple example using localStorage, note how it keeps the class settings after a refresh:

http://jsfiddle.net/73efLsht/

Comment: Just chill. They saw the id thing, decided to downvote (harsh, in my view), and haven't come back. Happens to all of us. :-)

Comment: I know, man. I love SO so much that I sometimes take such stupid things personally. It will be over soon. :)

Comment: Your answer worked as well. Thanks. But there is an update to my question, please read and if you can, tell me what is the solution?

Comment: I used your .class2 example, and it works fine. As well as other user's answers.

Comment: You're welcome, it has to work. :)  Now, about your update - the bigger problem is keeping those classes after a refresh than actually binding class changes to the click events. See my update.

Comment: actually the site users have the ability to change this class, so I am trying to make this happen: that a user changes a class by clicking on class1 and making it "class1 class2" .

Comment: I understand, then you can do what I did in that last example. If users have the ability to set different classes, that will work too. For example, you set the property `userClass` to whatever they choose and then directly apply it as a class name.

Answer (score 7):

Two problems with your code:

1. You're trying to look up `class1` as an `id`, but you don't have any element with `id="class1"`; I assume you want to look up elements with that *class*, but that's not what `getElementByid` does
2. You're *overwriting* the class list by assigning to `className`; instead, you need to *append* to it (including a space, so you end up with the right string).

If you want to add the second class to **all** elements that have `class1`, you'll need a loop:

```
[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll(".class1"), function(element) {
    element.className += " class2";
});
```

`querySelectorAll` works on all modern browsers, and also IE8. It accepts a CSS selector and returns a list of matching elements. Then, in the above, I loop over the list by borrowing `Array#forEach`, which is happy to loop through array-like things like the lists from `querySelectorAll`.

I should mention that if you want to use `forEach` on IE8, you'll need a polyfill for it. Or of course, use a boring old loop:

```
var list = document.querySelectorAll(".class1");
var n;
for (n = 0; n < list.length; ++n) {
    list[n].className += " class2";
}
```

---

Or if you only want to do it if they're inside a `.foo1`:

```
[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll(".foo1 .class1"), function(element) {
    element.className += " class2";
});
```

Or only *direct children* of a `.foo1`:

```
[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll(".foo1 > .class1"), function(element) {
    element.className += " class2";
});
```

Suggested reading:

- [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/)
- [DOM](http://www.w3.org/DOM/DOMTR)
- [CSS Selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/)

---

In case you're using jQuery and forgot to tag it (hey, it happens):

All:

```
$(".class1").addClass("class2");
```

Only inside a `.foo1`:

```
$(".foo1 .class1").addClass("class2");
```

Or only *direct children* of a `.foo1`:

```
$(".foo1 > .class1").addClass("class2");
```

Comment: actually, your code works, but since this is a click event, it temporarily adds the second class but when page is reloaded , it has disappeared. I need to implement it via a click event. How do I do it?

Comment: @مرتضیزاعری: When what is clicked?

Comment: @t-j-crowder my class1 is clickable, when I click on it, it adds the seocnd class2 to it. So this javascript code does the job of this clicking which adds another class to it.

Comment: @مرتضیزاعری: I really don't understand what you're asking, then. Your *original* question is answered, I suggest you write a new question focussing on the bit you still need, as A) Adding substantially to a question after it's been answered isn't really cool, and B) It sounds like you're really asking two questions anyway, so they should be separate.